# Why does the Blender SE specific badge icon only apply to the gold badge?

Tags: bug, badges

I have noticed something recently while using some Stack Exchange websites. Some sites have specific badge icons (the three 'medals': gold, silver, bronze). As you can see on the images below, some examples: [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com) and [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com) have that.

[image]

The default badge icons (simple circles) are seen for example on Stack Overflow:

[image]

On [Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com) we have a specific badge icon too: [Suzanne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blender_(software)#Suzanne) ([the 3D chimp](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cc/Suzanne.png)).

**However**, why is it only applied to the gold badge and not the other two?

[image]

Is that a bug or intentional? We want our Suzanne back on all three medals!

Comment: According to their [design discussion](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/988) all three were supposed to be different, and they are. (It may be hard to tell at smaller sizes, but the bronze and silver icons *are* different in your screenshot. One's a hexagon and the other's a circle.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you pay close attention, you'll see that the bronze badge (they're called *badges*, not *medals* on Stack Exchange) is different as well. It's a cube outline, not a circle. Incidentally, the silver circle isn't a circle either; it's the outline of a sphere.

For more details, see the [post about the site's design](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/988/32220) on Blender's own Meta:

> Badges: Use different glyphs for each badge type: (Bronze Cube / Silver Sphere / Gold Suzanne)

Implementing the design after graduation takes a while and allows for feedback by the community, and apparently everybody agreed with this design.

Comment: I hope your understand "We want our Suzanne back on all three medal!" was just for joking. I honestly don't care... And for the icons, I actually didn't realize there were three different icons. Thanks for the quick response. I think I have my answer now.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've removed that part of my answer.

Comment: No problem, also I should have posted this thread in Blender's own meta, but I didn't even know it existed...